# cygwin help trimming output

Tags: unix, cygwin, trim

```
ping google.com -n 10 | grep Minimum | sed s/^\ \ \ \ //
```

will output:

```
Minimum = 29ms, Maximum = 49ms, Average = 32ms
```

I want to trim from the space after the `=` to the the `,` in Minimum

So then it would only show:

```
29ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo "Minimum = 29ms, Maximum = 49ms, Average = 32ms" | awk '{print $3}' | sed s/,//
29ms
```

So this should work, but might not be the most elegant expression of your requirement.

```
ping google.com -n 10 | grep Minimum | awk '{print $3}' | sed s/,//
```

You could also use `cut` instead of `awk`.

Answer (score 3):

One way using `awk`:

```
ping google.com -n 10 | awk '/Minimum =/ { sub(",","",$3); print $3 }'
```

Comment: +1 for eliminating grep and consolidating the text manipulation.